# Difference between Jenkins pipeline and Shared library

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, shared-libraries

I wanted to get a clear understanding of the difference between Jenkins pipeline and Shared library concept. If someone using it can you kindly clarify. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A Jenkins Pipeline is usually one of many configurations that Jenkins has. A Pipeline is a very generic term for logic that is executed on a git repository for example.

On the other hand a shared library is like the name says a library that contains a specific function or logic. This specific function can be imported for multiple Jenkins Pipelines. A use case would be to prevent duplicate code.

An example would be you have a function that prints **Hello World**. Instead of writing the function 4 times for 4 Jenkins Pipelines - You create a shared library and import the function in each Pipeline. Basically just the base concept of libraries for programming languages.

The [official documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#defining-shared-libraries) describes it pretty well too:

> As Pipeline is adopted for more and more projects in an organization,
>   common patterns are likely to emerge. Oftentimes it is useful to share
>   parts of Pipelines between various projects to reduce redundancies and
>   keep code "DRY".

Answer (score 0):

I found this documentation for the Shared library. Hope this might help
https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/

Here is an example for the same:
https://tomd.xyz/jenkins-shared-library/

Comment: I have gone through that document. Is Jenkins pipeline and Shared libraries are different or both are same ? If both are different, what ways they are differing ?

Comment: Both are not same, they are different. 
Here refer to the following medium article [link](https://medium.com/spaceapetech/jenkins-pipelines-25ebc1980600).
and read from **Once we defined the first pipeline, we needed to start porting our other shared libraries over to use it.**